# Getting values from the database as list

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the Model:

```
class TreeComment(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Parent') 
   title = models.TextField(_('Title'), blank=True)
```

I want to call `TreeComment.objects.all()` and put result values into some list:

```
for e in TreeComment.objects.all():
    some_list += e
```

Is it possible to put all values into the list including the parent value?

Not whole parent object but id only (to prevent unnecessary DB calls and joins).
After that I will process it without DB calls inside the bussiness logic.

Comment: First, please format your code properly.  Edit the question, read the formatting guide on the right side of the page.  Second, please make your title describe your question.  The "Django ORM question" is obvious from the tags.  Please make the title more descriptive of what you want to know or do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to pull the query back as a list try

```
TreeComment.objects.values_list()
```

which would return [`(1, u'some title'), ...]` 1 being parent id and u'some title' being title's value

[values_list docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking 2 solutions

1) You create a method get_parent(self) inside TreeComment class. Then in your themplate you could do 
{% for elem in some_list %}{{ elem.get_parent.whatever_method }}{% endfor %}

2) You could use a custom structure containing (, title) and the populating method reads from your TreeComment.objects.all(), gets the parent and the title and populates your list with your custom couples